# D3 world-50m.json projection filling incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, map-projections

I have a projection of the `world-50m.json` file working, however when I fill it with a color there are several countries that are cut off on the edges which create horizontal fill sections/lines across the entire map.

This is actually visible on the d3-geo example projection here: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/test/data/world-50m.json

[image]

Is there another JSON file without these cutoff countries? Or perhaps I could omit specific polygons from my fill? Not quite sure how I'd locate every country/shape with the issue. While most are tiny and wouldn't be missed if omitted, a major one appears to be Russia.

Here is my code for reference:

```
var w = 960,
    h = 660,
    active = d3.select(null);

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(150)
    .translate([w/2, h/2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var countries = svg.append("svg:g").attr("id", "countries");

d3.json("world-50m.json", function(error, us) {
  mapFeatures = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.countries).features;
  mapFeatures.type = "countries";
  drawMap();
});

function drawMap() {
  countries.selectAll("path")
        .data(mapFeatures)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "feature")
        .attr("data-id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", ".2px");
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to include your `path` and `projection` in your code block too?

Comment: Your questions led me to the answer! I was using the wrong path projection. Should have been using `geoPath()` instead of `geo.path()` please answer the question so I can mark it correct :)

Comment: @MatOwen11 That is most likely not the correct interpretation. Have a look into *Antimeridian Cutting*, e.g. compare this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3788999) with to this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5735770) without antimeridian cutting.

Comment: @altocumulus very interesting stuff! I think you're right that the issue is the antimeridian cutting was not working. In this particular instance it seems I was using a projection call from d3 v4 with a path call from d3 v3. So my issue was solved by changing the path and projection formats to match the correct version of d3 which in turn, caused D3's geographic projection system which supports antimeridian cutting to start working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is detailed in the comments above and was achieved with the help of @Andrew Reid and @altocumulus.

The observed issue was an instance of *Antimeridian Cutting* that was not being properly handled by d3, due to a mismatch of path and projection calls between d3 v3 and d3 v4 syntax.

The issue was solved by changing `geo.path()` to `geoPath()` which corrected the mismatch and enabled d3 to render the map correctly with its antimeridian cutting support.

Below is the correct code:

```
var w = 960,
    h = 660,
    active = d3.select(null);

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(150)
    .translate([w/2, h/2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var countries = svg.append("svg:g").attr("id", "countries");

d3.json("world-50m.json", function(error, us) {
  mapFeatures = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.countries).features;
  mapFeatures.type = "countries";
  drawMap();
});

function drawMap() {
  countries.selectAll("path")
        .data(mapFeatures)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "feature")
        .attr("data-id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", ".2px");
};
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused. The `d3.geo.path()` call must have given you a Type Error, right? Something like *Cannot read property 'path' of undefined*. On the other hand you stated that you got it working. Can you fill me in on this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did not receive a Type Error which I believe was due to the fact that I had d3 v3 and d3 v4 initialized at the same time. This meant that the path and projection calls were routing to their respective versions of d3 but not working properly together. I left out my custom d3 variables from the question in an effort to simplify the problem, but I now realize including more context to my question would have helped.